# Django: Filter by less verbose (database name) on TextChoices class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model:

```py
class RegulationModel(models.Model):

    class Markets(models.TextChoices):
        EUROPE = 'E', 'Europe'
        US = 'US', 'US'
        JAPAN = 'J', 'Japan'
        KOREA = 'K', 'Korea'
        BRAZIL = 'B', 'Brazil'
        INDIA = 'I', 'India'
        CHINA = 'C', 'China'

    market = models.CharField(verbose_name='Market:', max_length=2, choices=Markets.choices)
    [... more fields ..]
```

**How do I filter on the more verbose choice in the `Markets` class?**

For example say I want to filter with "China", i'd like to do something like:

```py
regulation = RegulationModel.objects.get(market__verbose='China')
```

*(I know this isn't possible but it's just to get an idea)*

The reason why I am doing this is because I am getting the choice from AJAX therefore the format is not ["C","US"] .etc.

I was able to convert the verbose to the database value via:

```
>> market = 'China'
>> market_db = {y:x for x, y in RegulationModel.Markets._value2label_map_.items()}[market]
>> market_db
'C'
```

And then I could use this to query but it doesn't seem very pythonic.

Comment: ~~Hi! I can't think of a situation in which you would know the value 'China' but not 'C', and it's blocking my idea to think of a solution. Can you explain the use case? Otherwise~~ (I just read your question again) I would suggest having a lookup for the choices like `Model.objects.filter(market={v: k for k, v in Market.choices.items}['China'])`, which is pretty much what you wrote.

Comment: `Model.objects.filter(market={v: k for k, v in Market.choices}['China'])` i believe. You cannot get items. choices is already a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do following:

```py
china_code = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 'China', RegulationModel.Market.choices)).pop()[1]
regulation = RegulationModel.objects.get(market=china_code)
```

But it is a bit hacky. I recommend using [django-useful](https://pypi.org/project/django-useful/) and its implementation of Choices.

Comment: `django-useful` was last updated 2014.